# SARIMAX: Calculating the Seasional_order(P, D Q, M) values

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, pmdarima, sarimax

Is there a function or library (like auto_arima to get the order(p,d,q) values) available to calculate the P, D, Q and M values to be used in Seasional_order(P,D,Q,M) in SARIMAX model.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The auto_arima function can do that. You can set the parameter `seasonal = True` and give the length of the season with the parameter `m`:

`auto_arima(y=your_data, seasonal=True, m=length)`

If you want to only use the seasonal components without the non-seasonals, then you can manually turn them off by setting the respective parameters to 0:

`auto_arima(y=your_data, seasonal=True, m=length, p=0, d=0, q=0)`

However, auto_arima cannot really detect whether your data is stationary and therefore, you need to estimate the `d` and `D` parameters yourself and manually set them in the `auto_arima` function.

https://alkaline-ml.com/pmdarima/modules/generated/pmdarima.arima.auto_arima.html